# Django extend admin home page - Add elements to the content area

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to add a link inside the content area of the admin home page. I'm using this template:

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Custom title
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <a href="some/url">LINK</a>
{% endblock %}
```

The title is working so I know the extended template is working but the block content is not working, I can't see the link in my admin home page. Acoording to django's github repository (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) the block name is correct so I don't know where my error is.

How can I add elements to the content area of my admin home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `{% block content %}` is getting overridden by other templates in the django admin.

For e.g. `contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html` will override the `content` block, as will all other admin pages.

Since you only want to change the Django Admin homepage, you can override this template instead `admin/templates/admin/index.html`

Comment: But which template should I extend? or what can I do to add the links I need to the admin home page?

Comment: The template for the admin home page is `admin/templates/admin/index.html`

Comment: I was able to make it work by overriding index.html, had to add the new html elements to the sidebar block instead of using the content block so that they would appear only in the admin index page and not in the app.app_url pages, this because the index.html is extended by other templates with different purposes.